# Configuration domain name on nginx on linux?

Tags: nginx, configuration, localhost

I am installing grandnode on ubuntu server. I installed nginx and configured it as a reverse proxy. In the sites-available directory, I created the reverse-proxy.conf file and wrote the following code in it:

```
server {
listen 80;
location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

And i was able to access the site using my ip address. But now, how do I access the site by domain name? For example: example.com

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a custom conf file in /etc/nginx/conf.d/ directory?

Working file /etc/nginx/conf.d/reverse-proxy.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Make sure after the changing nginx configuration reload or restart.

Comment: I have also done this way but failed. When I accessed with example.com, it still displayed: This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission. :(((

Comment: nginx has no errors. I mean: I tried adding the above code but still could not access the website with the domain name: example.com.

Comment: What happens after the ping example.com? Is it hit the correct server IP address and you tired on the local network?